# autoconf - checking for programs/locations used during installation

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

Should `configure` check for programs used to install files (such as `unzip` for example), or is that the job of the `Makefile`? The same applies for directory existence - should `configure` check that a user-defined directory actually exists (for example, to enable a certain feature of the program which needs to install files into a different location)? Both of these are install-time checks, but `automake` doesn't seem to have any capabilities to do this, only `autoconf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `configure`s job to do system discovery tasks.  If you need `unzip` for a customized install step, `configure` should discover it or be directed to it (e.g. via `AC_ARG_VAR`).
Enabling features is IMO better handled by `AC_ARG_WITH` or `AC_ARG_ENABLE`, because you can always create the directory as part of `make install`.  But if you'd rather check for the existence of the directory, `configure` is the place to do it.

Comment: I have options to manually configure directories using `AC_ARG_WITH`, but my question was more catered to auto-discovery. I suppose the same applies as for `unzip`, that `configure` should try and detect features available, with the option to override them with `AC_ARG_{ENABLE,WITH}`?

Comment: The answer is yes, I'd try and discover `unzip`, but set up an `AC_ARG_VAR` to escape bad discovery.  I usually try and provide a way to override tools not on the [usual list of tools](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Limitations-of-Usual-Tools), because sometimes it'll be the wrong one discovered.